# jquery ui not working

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I am trying to make some tabs with the Jquery ui.

My html looks lie this...

```
<html>

<head>

    <!--use for jquery-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--external javascript source-->
    <script type= "text/javascript" src= "javascript/home_scripts.js"> </script>

    <!--css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/homepage.css" />


</head>

<body>

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="panes">
        <div>First tab content. Tab contents are called "panes"</div>
        <div>Second tab content</div>
        <div>Third tab content</div>
    </div>




</body>


</html>
```

and my javascript file looks like so

```
$(function() {
// setup ul.tabs to work as tabs for each div directly under div.panes
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
});
```

The problem is that when I load my page, there are no tabs. It looks like this

```
Tab 1
Tab 2
Tab 3
First tab content. Tab contents are called "panes"
Second tab content
Third tab content
```

What have I done wrong? I tried to follow the tutorial as best as I could.

Comment: have your referenced the jquery ui library anywhere?

Comment: where and how would I do this ?

Comment: As you have included jQuery library, in the same way you also need to include jQuery-UI library. <http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js>

Comment: now my set up is 

    <!--use for jquery-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <!--javascript-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
  
  
  <!--external javascript source-->
  <script type= "text/javascript" src= "javascript/home_scripts.js"> </script>
  
  <!--css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/homepage.css" />

but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your markup to:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">First tab content. Tab contents are called "panes"</div>
    <div id="tab2">Second tab content</div>
    <div id="tab3">Third tab content</div>
</div>
```

and your JavaScript to:

```
$(function () {
    $("div.tabs").tabs();
});
```

The `.tabs()` function does not take a selector as a parameter. It uses the `innerHTML` structure of the selected element to make the tabs. Ideally, the `href` on your anchors should point to an `id` on the corresponding "pane"

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
// setup ul.tabs to work as tabs for each div directly under div.panes
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
});
```

This is an anonymous function. So when the page loads the browser will not be able to recognise this since you are not calling this function in anyways... So probably one of the two possible methods might work..

```
$(function() {
// setup ul.tabs to work as tabs for each div directly under div.panes
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
})();
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
});
```

should work. I am not sure though. Have to check it out. But a similar logic should work. And also you have not included the jquery.ui.js file in your html page. I suppose you forgot to include it in the sample that you posted here. Otherwise its a huge bummer for me :P :)

Comment: how do I include this?? I did not include it

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
You could include this. Simillar to hosting jquery google also hosts jqueryui.